# OpenSSL error when running "make" command

Tags: bitcoin-core, openssl

I am trying to install bitcoin core on my ubuntu server.
installed necessary dependencies.
RAN :
./autogen.sh
./configure --disable-wallet --with-incompatible-bdb --with-gui=no
./configure
make

I am getting OpenSSL errors when I run make.

> bignum.h:593:77: error: cannot convert ‘const CBigNum*’ to ‘const BIGNUM*’ {aka ‘const bignum_st*’}
> 593 | inline bool operator>(const CBigNum& a, const CBigNum& b)  { return (BN_cmp(&a, &b) > 0); }
> |                                                                             ^~
> |                                                                             |
> |                                                                             const CBigNum*
> In file included from /usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:23,
> from /usr/include/openssl/objects.h:15,
> from /usr/include/openssl/evp.h:28,
> from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:18,
> from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:20,
> from /usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/openssl_types.hpp:24,
> from /usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/context_base.hpp:19,
> from /usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:23,
> from /usr/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:18,
> from rpcprotocol.h:16,
> from rpcserver.h:10,
> from bitcoind.cpp:6:
> /usr/include/openssl/bn.h:274:26: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘int BN_cmp(const BIGNUM*, const BIGNUM*)’
> 274 | int BN_cmp(const BIGNUM *a, const BIGNUM *b);
> |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
> make[3]: *** [Makefile:865: bitcoind.o] Error 1
> make[3]: Leaving directory '/root/bitcoin/src'
> make[2]: *** [Makefile:887: all-recursive] Error 1
> make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/bitcoin/src'
> make[1]: *** [Makefile:673: all] Error 2
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/bitcoin/src'
> make: *** [Makefile:509: all-recursive] Error 1

I did run **sudo apt-get install libssl-dev** but it doesn't help.

Comment: What version of Bitcoin Core is this? Modern versions don't use OpenSSL at all anymore.

Comment: @PieterWuille 0.9.5

Comment: That's almost 6 years old. I suggest you use 0.21.0 (which was released 2 weeks ago), or at least something that's still supported.

Comment: @PieterWuille Thank you. Using version 0.21.0 solved my problem